# sublime text 2 link between html and css, github add-ons

Tags: html, css, web

I thought the way to link your html file to your css file is to write:

```
<link type= "text/css" rel= "firststylesheet" href= "firststylesheet.css"/>
```

(given my css file name is `firststylesheet.css`) but when I uploaded the css and html file onto my website, the css file didn't connect, and all the site was reading was my html file. How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like part of your post is missing (the code).

Comment: What you need to do is to put the full path to see is the file is already on your server. ex: www.yourdomain/css/yourcss.css. If this is working, that mean your file is on the server and you need to change the path to get your css. (try add ../ to go back to the previous folder). Otherwise, look inside the console, you will get the error.

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to Sublime Text 2. I'd like to submit an edit, but before I do, can you explain what Sublime Text 2 has to do with your question?

Answer (score 5):

'rel' attribute has to be "stylesheet" and not "firststylesheet"

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="firststylesheet.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I noticed that my css, called Stylesheet, missed the ".css". So i manually renamed it stylesheet.css and it worked :)